# Can I use a regression machine learning model for predicting a vector with multiple values?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

### Introduction

I have a large CSV file with about `400 rows`.

Each row contains `1000 x values` and `400 y values`.

Thus, my current model is taking in a row of 1000 x values and predicting a row of 400 y values:

(input) `1000 x values` ----> (neural network) ----> `400 y values` (output prediction)

The challenge is the `400 y values` are not one hot vectors.E.g, they are not all zero's with 1 y having a value:

```
[0,0,0,0,0,...,1,0,0]
```

The `400 y values` actually contain multiple discrete values, like so:

```
[0,13,0,23,5,...,1,85,0]
```

### Keras model:

```
# Intialize the artificial neural network
model = Sequential()

# Input layer and hidden layer 
model.add(Dense(activation="relu", input_dim=1000, units=700, kernel_initializer="uniform"))

# Dropout to aid overfitting
model.add(Dropout(0.285))

# Output layer
model.add(Dense(activation="linear", input_dim=700, units=400, kernel_initializer="uniform"))

# Compile the ANN
model.compile(optimizer="adagrad", loss="mean_squared_error", metrics=["accuracy"])
```

Then I fit my data to the training set:

```
# Fit the ANN to the training set
model = baseline_model()
result = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=10, nb_epoch=200, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

### Question

Is it okay to use my model for this machine learning problem? Or is my neural network in Keras incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit too little information on the actual inputs, outputs and use-case to answer this question properly. However, I will try to give you some intuition for thoughts:

What you are essentially doing is reducing the dimensions of the input. This is legit as you seem to be intending to do that: for each row you provide a vector of [1000x1] and want to get [400x1] that represents your original input the best way possible.

**Let's look at your architecture:**
In the hidden layer you are using a ReLu activation function, so your outputs from that layer will be sparse: zeroes and ones. Then you apply a linear layer, so your transformation on the output layer is of the format b*v+bias where b is the vector of the hidden layer and v the weight vector between hidden and output layer. This implies that v does not influence the zero elements of b, but solely the bias determines their values after the transformation. It's hard to tell whether that's good or bad. Anyway, you may want to think about trying out continuous functions at the hidden layer, such as a Sigmoid. Furthermore, using a uniform distribution for weight initialization of your network is not quite ideal in most cases. A truncated normal distribution is a common choice of initialization, however, again, it depends on your input and output data.

Maybe you would like to provide more information on the data for us to help you better?

If your goal is to get a more low-dimensional representation of your data and not care about the exact target values, you may want to look into [AutoEncoders](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html).